# Strongly Typed Repository Return Types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm, repository

So I've been doing a lot of programming in Entity Framework 6 recently, and I'm rather annoyed with a certain behavior regarding eager loading.

Take this:

```
var customers = _db.Customers.Where(c => c.IsActive);
var customersWithOrders = _db.Customers.Include(c => c.Orders).Where(c => c.IsActive);

customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders).DoSomething(...); // NRE
customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders).DoSomething(...); // Works
```

I understand I can actually enable lazy loading in EF, but that's something I'd like to avoid doing as it would merely turn this into a Select N+1 problem.

What I don't like about this is that both queries are actually returning different types of data even though their signatures are essentially `IEnumerable<Customer>` If I were to write my own repository on top of EF, I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
public class CustomerRepo {
    IEnumerable<T> GetCertainCustomers<T>(...);
    IEnumerable<T> DifferentCustomerQuery<T>(...);
    IEnumerable<T> YetAnotherQuery<T>(...);
}

public class Customer {...}
public class CustomerWithOrders : Customer { public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set;} }
public class CustomerWithPaymentMethods : Customer { public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set;} }
```

Something like the above would actually work fine, the repository conducts the correct amount of eager loading given the type parameter T.

**My problem with this is that the number of types is going to explode if you have more than 2-3 different eager loading options, not to mention what happens when you want to eager load more than one relationship!**

FYI all of the above code is just for illustration, it's not real.

Comment: I do not understand what problem you are trying to solve. If you do not want to create specialized types, the do not create them. Both [Table Per Hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716683(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Table-Per-Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716702(v=vs.100).aspx)  work fairly well depending on your particular requirements and are a well known, established patterns. Could explain in a little bit more details what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: In particular, what is "NRE"? Which two queries returning different type of data, and why the types are different? What exactly is "correct amount of eager loading"? Is not eager loading regulated by EF query that you write as opposed to a type that your repository class/method accepts?

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about null reference exceptions *in particular*, you can simply give your `Orders` an empty collection by default.

For example:

```
public class Customer
{
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public Customer()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
}
```

Loading a customer without `.Include(c => c.Order)` means the collection will stay *empty* but not *null*. This means that your examples:

```
customers.SelectMany(c => c.Orders).DoSomething(...);
customersWithOrders.SelectMany(c => c.Orders).DoSomething(...);
```

Will both work (the first one would simply do nothing, as the collection is empty).

In any case, you *should* be doing null checks where appropriate. If your method requires customers with orders, *it should check that*. Having a class defined which merely describes what information is or is not null in the object is a bad idea.